# Django in Aptana: Have to restart server for changes in python code to take affect

Tags: django, debugging, aptana, restart

Unless I'm going crazy, I didn't have to do this as of a few days ago. For example, changes to HTML files do not require a server restart to take affect, but when I do simple modifications to, say, my views.py file, I need to restart the server. Is this how it is and I'm am actually going crazy, or is there a configuration that needs fixing?

Also, my debugger stopped working at around the same time. I set breakpoints in functions I know should get touched, but when I debug the code, it stops at "manage.py" in the debug tree. I'm wondering if the two problems are related.

Comment: Anytime you make a change to a .py file, you'll need to restart the server. If you started the server "manage.py runserver", it'll detect changes and restart itself automatically. Eclipse and Aptana need to have the Django Dev server started with the " --noreload" option to work properly. That turns off the auto restart.

Comment: Strange things like these seem to happen when python decides to just use the compiled .pyc files, instead of checking the .py files for changes.  Try removing all the .pyc files, see if that fixes it. (Then again, it may be that Aptana's appending the `--noreload` option, like Evan mentioned)

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to this on a random foot note on a blog some where!

In Aptana under preference (or any where else you deal/launch the run server) do this:
Aptana -> Preference -> Pydev -> Interpreter - Python -> "Environment" tab
add a new variable here called:
PYTHONUNBUFFERED = Y
Name             = Value ..

vola! it works now no more reloading of the runserver .. or resaving of your py file to trigger a print out.